# Jackson @JsonFormat changes time in date with 2hours back

Tags: json, date, spring-boot, jackson

I have strange problem with `Dates - java.util.Date`. In my database I have a row with a date like that:

[image]

It show it is 10:30 time. But when I create an REST api and go to the developer tools in Chrome I see that the time was changed with 2 hours, e.g:

[image]

In my application properties I added two things:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

And my model class looks like (with @JsonFormat):

```
import java.util.Date; <- look I have java.util.Date, not Yoda.

import com.carwash.utils.JsonDateSerializer;
import com.carwash.utils.ReviewStatus;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class ReservationModel {
    private String code;
    //@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private Date date;
```

Comment: Can you debug and see what is the string representation of `date` field in Java layer before Jackson serialization happens. I doubt this mismatch happens because your DB date is in a different timezone and java.util.date is representing it in different timezone.

Comment: Did you tried with different timezone? CEST?